# What is this stalked herbaceous berry?

Tags: identification, berries

Found this growing in Northern California in the wild. It features large arrow shaped herbaceous leaves at the base and several long stalks with some sort of berry/fruit on the ends.

It looks like the berries start green and turn red with slight spikes on them.

I didnt notice any flowers at the time, but upon viewing the image closer up, it may have black flowers?

[image: Low laying plant with large arrow shaped leaves and stalks with berries on the ends]